# What does app class means?

Tags: android-development, react

In framworks for developing app whether it be a joomla or react or angular i see app class. What does it mean. Like if there is some user class, or some input class or that make sense for some purpose we are creating these. what about app class for what purpose one creats app class.
thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is usually simply is the top level element/component or the entry point of your application. It got common practice to name it `App` but essentially there is no need to do that. The name can be something of your choice.

Comment: Top level of element. In android it has some things activity and services.  it has global variable. I still don't get it. Can i get some analogy or some link, why we are doing this creating app class.

Comment: @bikashamit I'm not actually sure if the question has any relevance. Why is your name `bikashamit`? It is a convention that has been established. Also in every framework the `App` class or component can serve a different purpose. You will have to figure it out per framework.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am confused with purpose of doing with name.

Comment: @bikashamit Or to frame it differently: The `App` component in a react application and the `App` class in an android app are not in any way related except they are both named `App`. It is a different language and framework. They are something completely different. It is coincidence. You are focusing way too much on the name. Just figure out what it does. And that is something different for every language and framework.

Comment: But both are doing same job making an app and making a class name app may be common. What is purpose of making a class at core for an app.

Comment: @bikashamit I don't really understand where you want to get. It is just an entry point to your app. E.g. react requires you to pass a component to your initial `ReactDOM.render`. So most people just define it somewhere and call it `App`. But you could call it `Foo` too. It wouldn't make a difference. You just have to start somewhere. It has no deeper purpose than to be the starting point. I don't get where you are trying to get here.

Comment: Also as I already said the `App` class in an android application may be something completely different than in a React application. In fact, a react application does not need to have a component called `App` at all. You are searching commonalities where there are none.

Comment: Pass a component to your intial render.  For that you are making one class and more purpose. Thank you so much

Comment: Yeah i was searching common. And had some class name app has to do some thing with real app which executes.